# Incorrect new user text box

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, new-users

Q: What is Ubuntu?

A: Apparently, Ubuntu is a collaboratively edited question and answer site for people who love Ubuntu.

[image: Ubuntu is...]

I think Canonical may not approve of that assessment ;).  Don't know if this is just a simple typo or due to a bad template swap somewhere but it should definitely say "AskUbuntu is...".

Comment: That appears to be a typo, but I agree it should be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added "Ask" to the beginning of that string :)